# How to use redislab free tier with the Hydra-router docker container?

Tags: node.js, docker, redis, microservices

I have been trying to implement micro-services using the cool hydra package for micro-services.It uses Redis database for "coordinating" the services.I have setup a free tier on Redislabs.
I have created 2 services using hydra-express and they do run properly.However,I wish to use the hydra-router as I want the services to be accessed from outside the system .And according to this [page](https://www.hydramicroservice.com/docs/tools/hydra-router/) I need a local Redis setup.What can I do to use the redislab setup itself and run the hydra-router?Also,the Redis database on Redislabs is password protected

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? I can't connect the hydra-cli to the redislabs server and i assume it has something to do with the password protection. But hydra-cli doesn't give any option to set up a password in the connection cofiguration.

Comment: Hey man in the off-case you are still looking for a solution. I ended up editing the actual hydra-cli code to add password functionality. You can read about it and get the code here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51962781/conecting-hydra-cli-to-a-password-protect-redis-server/51963565#51963565